# Spring Security Ignores all requests when you should just ignore the OPTIONS requests

Tags: spring, spring-security

Before GET/POST request the client make a OPTIONS request, so I keep this calls ignored. But when I make this configuration, the another requests(GET/POST) are ignored too (but should not ignore).

When I add this line:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
```

All requests are ignored, but the GET/POST should not ignored.

The following is the configuration method:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS); 
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login/authenticate").authenticated()

        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/credenciadas**").hasRole(PermissaoEnum.CONSULTAR_CREDENCIADA.getNomeInterno())
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/credenciadas/validar").hasRole(PermissaoEnum.CONSULTAR_CREDENCIADA.getNomeInterno())
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/credenciadas").hasRole(PermissaoEnum.INCLUIR_CREDENCIADA.getNomeInterno())
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/credenciadas/alterar").hasRole(PermissaoEnum.ALTERAR_CREDENCIADA.getNomeInterno())
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/credenciadas/").hasRole(PermissaoEnum.EXCLUIR_CREDENCIADA.getNomeInterno())

    .and()
    .addFilterBefore(authenticationByTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
    .and()
    .csrf().disable();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you verify if you set the prefix string at role name as: "ROLE_"? The role name could be wrong.